# How to get all element tags <a> from current page

Tags: c#, watin

I need to get all element tags  from current page into a list by using WatiN codes.

I have used this:

```
var listItmes=ie.Links;  [not getting all links]
```

Please tell me the solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

That should get you all the links on the current page.  The one exception I've found is if you have a frame on the page (in which case you need to look for links in the frame).